# How to perform some tasks with an incoming request before saving it or responding with django rest framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, model

I'm quite new to django, i'm trying to migrate and old API built in express to Django Rest Framework,
brief story:
The API is meant to receive different kind of payplods from different device, in example

```
{
   "device": "device001",
   "deviceType": "temperature_device",
   "deviceTs": timestamp,
   "payload": {
      "airTemp": X,
      "airHum": Y,
   }
}
```

the payload wouldn't be always the same, so other devices (different type) will bring different key - value pairs in the "payload" field.

I'm using Django Rest Framework, alongside model serializers and and GenericViewSet,

but the problem is that before storing the data to the DB and returning the HTTP Response, I need to perform a data validation (minimum, and maximum values) and in some cases, the device sends some "corrupted" data (In example: Negatives number comes with the following syntax: 1.-5 instead of -1.5), I need to fix these values and so on, finally, I need to perform two HTTP request to an external API with the fixed payload and and API Key (that should be stored in the device details model in my database)

so, in short how can I perform any kind of -previous work- to a request BEFORE storing the data into the DB and returning the HTTP response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive your payload in `request.data` then you will have to serialize it and validate your payload according to your requirements.

Here is the [DRF serilization document](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) which would help you understand how exactly serialization works.

And here is the [DRF Validators documents](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/) to understand how validators work.